# Dropdown filter jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Initialise the DataTable */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        },
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bFilter": true,
    }); 

    /* Add a select menu for each TH element in the table footer */
    $("thead th").each( function ( i ) {
        this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
        $('select', this).change( function () {
            oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
        } );
    } );        
} );
```

Im using the jquery datatables plugin, its working perfectly just like this example:

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

What i would like to do is rather than having a dropdown for each column i would like a dropdown only on one specific column.

So i presume i need to change:

```
$("thead th").each( function ( i ) {
```

But im not sure what to put. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think using 'i' you can control which column you want to show into

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can also create your own select list and position it anywhere you like outside the table.

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    ...
</select>

<script>
    $('#mySelect').on('change',function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        oTable.fnFilter("^"+selectedValue+"$", 0, true); //Exact value, column, reg
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This in my opinion is the best answer and usage

Comment: this supposes that you already know the values of that column , sometimes it's not the case

Comment: But if bStateSave set to true, you'll not get the selected value after refresh

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: oTable is not defined. Is this answer working in 2021? I am getting the error

Comment: var oTable = $('#example').DataTable(); 
    $('#main_cat_select').on('change',function(){
   var selectedValue = $(this).val();
   oTable.column( 3 )
                    .search( selectedValue )
                    .draw();
  });

Comment: 3 is column number. @user9437856 you can use like that.

Answer (score 12):

If you need only on one column you could do

```
var indexOfMyCol = 2;//you want it on the third column
$("thead th").each( function ( i ) {
    if(i === indexOfMyCol){ 
      this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
      $('select', this).change( function () {
        oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
      } );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks, so easy when you think about it :) Can i Give the dropdown a title? like.... Please select

Comment: @Codded in `fnCreateSelect` replace var `r='<select><option value=""></option>',` with `var r='<select><option value="">Please Select</option>',`

Comment: Im not switched on today, could have worked that one out :) Thanks for the help

Comment: How about sorting the select into alphabetical order?

Comment: @Codded on line 52 before `return asResultData;`  you should aplly a sort to `asResultData`

Comment: asResultData.sort();
return asResultData;

Comment: Error:  "missing : after property id"

Comment: fnCreateSelect is not defined -- possibly an old answer?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe times have changed, but with no plugin and using [dataTables](https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) `1.10.12`and it's `@api`, as a person in the comments suggested, you can use the zero based index integer from an array for the corresponding table. Example code, important bits are on line `2` below. I'm searching just on the 4th column, and this is coffeescript but you get the idea.

```
    $('#example').DataTable initComplete: ->
                    @api().columns([3]).every ->
                            column = this
                            select = $('<select><option value="">Sort Column(All)</option></select>').appendTo($(column.header()).empty()).on('change', ->
                                    val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val())
                                    column.search(val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false).draw()
                                    return
                            )
                            column.data().unique().sort().each (d, j) ->
                                    select.append '<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>'
                                    return
                            return
                    return
```

Answer (score 2):

I  think something like following might do the trick

```
$("thead th").each( function ( i ) {
    if(i==1)
    {
        this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
        $('select', this).change( function () {
            oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
        } ); 
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you, i have used the other answer but this would work aswel :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use date tables column filter see http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customFilters.html

It is a second level plugin for datatables.

Jovan

Answer (score 2):

You can use the columnfilter plugin...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#example').dataTable()
          .columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [ { type: "select", values: [ 'Gecko', 'Trident', 'KHTML', 'Misc', 'Presto', 'Webkit', 'Tasman']  },
                     { type: "text" },
                     null,
                     { type: "number" },
             { type: "select" }
                ]

        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="dropdown1">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="London">London</option>
<option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$('#dropdown1').on('change', function() {
table.columns(1).search(this.value).denter code hereraw();
});
});
```